# What's the appropriate Stack Exchange site for asking about a software library to solve a particular problem?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, scope

I have recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74904015/is-there-a-single-python-module-for-working-with-multiple-types-of-compressed-fi) on Stack Overflow, asking about the existence of a Python module to solve a particular problem, and the question was closed due to being "off-topic". However, I believe my question is clear, reasonable and relevant. What is the proper channel to ask it? Or is it a question that doesn't belong to the Stack Exchange community altogether?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Software recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) includes [software library recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in their scope.

Since software recs *explicitly* allows shopping questions of a sort, they do have slightly stricter requirements on questions - so I'd encourage you to read through and understand the [quality requirements for the site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)